# Mounting a drive speific to a user in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, automount, mountpoint

Need to mount a specific folder in hard disk specific to a user in group.

Eg:

1. System has *a group* called development which has *many users*
2. A folder(/mnt/worksite/projects/documents of /dev/sda3) in hard disk should be mounted to user usr1 alone
3. This folder should be *auto mounted on startup* for usr1

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a local hard disk (ie not nfs or samba?) and using a linux format like ext4? Is it a separate partition you want to mount for each user, or just part of a directory structure on a partition?

Comment: Would it work to mount /dev/sda3 as a normal disk, and simply set the permissions of documents so that they are ownerd by user usr1, and no access rights are given to anyone other than the owner?

Comment: It is a local hard disk using *ntfs* format. I need to mount a part of directory, not entire dirve.

Comment: I just don't want user usr1 to see directory structure present in /dev/sda3. A *part of directory* in /dev/sda3 should be *made visible to usr1* alone with proper rw access and he\she will not be the owner.

Comment: Sorry. I am not an NTFS user